# Passing arguments dynamically to a batch file by using php

Tags: php, server, copy, vpn

Here is my batch file script. I would like to pass arguments dynamically to the batch file. Based on the file name as part of the query string, it should copy that specific file to the network folder.

```
Echo off
set arg1=%1
net use \\windows_servername\test_folder shared_folder_password /user:shared_folder_username
xcopy C:\Apache\htdocs\Invoices\invoice_feed\%arg1% \\windows_servername\\test_folder
```

my PHP file code is below

```
echo $fname = $_GET['FILE_NAME'];
system("cmd /c C:\\scripts\batch1.bat ".$fname);
```

I am getting out put as The command was successfully completed. But file was not copied to the network folder.

But It is working fine, when I gave the file name directly on batch file like below.

```
xcopy C:\Apache\htdocs\Invoices\invoice_feed\sample.csv \\windows_servername\\test_folder
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.